# The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim for PS3. im stuck and cant get unstuck

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to complete the main story quests and have come across season unending. I also have the Stormcloak quest: *The jagged crown*.

It says I need to talk to Galmar about the crown. But in order to talk to him, I have to complete the peace treaty. And to complete that, I have to talk to Ulfric. But he just tells me to talk to Galmar instead of letting me tell him about the peace treaty, and I can't talk to Galmar.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

At your stage in the quest line you must complete [The Jagged Crown](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Jagged_Crown_(Stormcloaks)) before [Season Unending](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending). This was intentionally implemented by the developers to prevent this quest conflicting with the civil war quest line. It sounds like "Talk to Galmar" is your current objective for that quest, but he only speaks of the treaty?

Firstly, keep pestering Galmar. Talk to him over and over, interrupt him if you have to. This may get him to speak the dialog you're looking for.

If that doesn't work, reload the last save (most likely after just entering High Hrothgar) and speak to Galmar before anyone else, this may prevent Season Unending progressing too far and changing his dialog.

As a last resort, if you can return to a save prior to starting Season Unending that will allow you to complete The Jagged Crown. Then you should be able to do Season Unending without issue (not this issue anyway!).

Also, make sure the game is updated to the latest version. <strike>Most</strike> Many bugs will be quelled by official updates.

Comment: thanks for the advice but my only saves are since starting season unending. I did not even know I had the jagged crow quest until I started this one. any I deas on how to progress from here?

Comment: ive ended up just starting the game over. I wasn't exactly happy with my character so why not. it solve the issue too so win win I guess.

Comment: General rule of thumb for all Bethesda games:  Save early, save often, keep lots of saves.  I literally had to go back 5 months (real time) worth of saves to undo a bug preventing me from continuing the Dawnstar quest line.  Someone needs to make a list of "things you shouldn't do early, things you must do early" to avoid these kinds of bugs.

Comment: @ReginaldBlue I'm curious what that bug is.

Comment: @Nelson Don't visit Castle Volkihar (specifically don't talk to the gatekeeper) before you have Serana with you.  If you do, the gate will never open.  I visited it early out of curiosity, and then could never get the quest line to continue when I went back months (real time) later.  That's, of course, just an example.  The game is sadly filled with those kinds of things.